# GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR when using glfwSetWindowIcon()

Tags: java, lwjgl

I currently coding a Project using LWJGL 3. Since GLFW 3.2 its possible to add a window icon. I used it like you can see below, but I keep getting the error, and I have no clue why. What am I doing wrong?

**What I have tried already:**

- I have made sure that the file is present in "res/img/icon.png".
- The PNGLoader (Found [here](http://twl.l33tlabs.org/dist/PNGDecoder.jar)) works, as I am using textures and it loads them without any problems.

**Code:**

```
PNGDecoder dec = null;
try {
    dec = new PNGDecoder(new FileInputStream("res/img/icon.png"));
    int width = dec.getWidth();
    int height = dec.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * 4);
    dec.decode(buf, width * 4, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);
    buf.flip();
    Buffer images = new Buffer(buf);
    GLFW.glfwSetWindowIcon(window, images);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the **error** that I get:

```
[LWJGL] GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR error
    Description : Win32: Failed to create RGBA bitmap
    Stacktrace  :
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwSetWindowIcon(GLFW.java:1802)
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetWindowIcon(GLFW.java:1829)
        ch.norelect.emulator.designer.Designer.initialize(Designer.java:81)
        ch.norelect.emulator.designer.Designer.start(Designer.java:48)
        ch.norelect.emulator.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the raw pixel data as a `GLFWImage.Buffer`, but GLFW needs the width and height as well. `GLFWImage.Buffer` is just a convenience class for putting several `GLFWImage`s next to each other, which each hold properties about an image.

```
GLFWImage image = GLFWImage.malloc();
image.set(width, height, buf);
GLFWImage.Buffer images = GLFWImage.malloc(1);
images.put(0, image);

glfwSetWindowIcon(window, images);

images.free();
image.free();
```